# How to correctly put a jLabel in jPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I've watched through several questions on this topic and it seems like I've done everything as it's told in the answers to them, but still I can't manage to make it work.
I have a custom jPanel with an image on the background. I want to put a jLabel in that jPanel. The code compiles and I can see my jPanel, but i cant see the jLabel

```
ImagePanel ip = null;
    try {
        ip = new ImagePanel(backGround);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("", JLabel.LEFT);//initialize the label
        label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().
                getResource("/facemask.png")));
        ip.add(label);//now add it
        jFrame.add(ip);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    };
```

this is the class that's for the custom jPanel

```
public ImagePanel(BufferedImage backGround) throws IOException {
    image = backGround;
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(gl);

    gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0,480,Short.MAX_VALUE));

    gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0,596,Short.MAX_VALUE));
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters            
    g.dispose();
}
```

I've tried using usual JPanel and everything worked ok, it seems like the problem is in using a custom JPanel or some code that I've used in the properties of the JPanel. Any ideas?

PS
I'm new to Swing, so please don't be harsh on me if I made some stuoid mistake )

Comment: Try using .addComponent instead of .add so

ip.addComponent(label);

Comment: You should never dispose the Graphics instance passed in to paintComponent()

Comment: @TomMonTom Hm, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but my IDE doesn't see a method with a name addComponent, only addComponentListener

Comment: @FredK found that in another question, maybe I didn't get the idea in that answer.

Comment: Found the answer after folowing one of the related questions on the given link.

The problem was that I didn't set the bounds and didn't repaint the panel after adding the label